# Is it possible to use Ignition in Google Cloud offered Container Optimised OS?

Tags: google-compute-engine, coreos-ignition

We have an GCE instance running on CoreOs which is going to have its end of Life by May 26, 2020. So I would like to upgrade/Migrate my instance to Container Optimised OS. So I would like to understand if it is possible to use Ignition in COS config, as we have set the configuration using Ignition in CoreOS. It will make our lives easier.
Is there way that I can use Ignition in COS. If yes any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Since Core OS is part of the Container Optimized OS family, then you should be able to run Ignition within the Container Optimized OS. I was also able to find a GitHub page that shows how to use Ignition with docker [link](https://github.com/thirdgen88/ignition-docker)

Comment: But Unfortunately its not supporting ignition configuration. I got the below error 
Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: '{"ignition":{"config":{}...'

Answer (score 0):

Compute Engine requires specific guest environment packages. Ignition will choose where to look for configuration based on the underlying platform. In Google Compute Platform, it will read its configuration from the instance metadata entry named "user-data".

I have found a github [page](https://github.com/coreos/docs/blob/master/os/booting-on-google-compute-engine.md) on Running CoreOS Container Linux on Google Compute Engine with examples and how to [troubleshoot](https://github.com/coreos/ignition/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#troubleshooting) the issue.

Comment: Yeah I did something similar to this. I tried to convert the config to use cloud-config from the existing ignition system by following some examples in coreos documents